# I have a method X in Java. How could I know for how much time this method has been running?

Tags: java, spring, infinite-loop, spring-aop

I have n number of different methods having multiple while loop. Those while loop have higher chances of going to infinite loop.

I want to have a common code / something which will calculate the total duration a method has been running for and has not stopped yet.
This common code will find that and exit that method and log something for debugging purpose.

Comment: Depends on if you can modify the method, or intercept the call to it. You'll probably have to run some code concurrently with the method to do measurements/timeouts for logging. Please provide more information.

Comment: you could configre an aop before and after on that method. log a timestamp on each

Comment: I believe aop would work in a way like before method call and after method call. But in my case, I want to calculate the time taken till now when method is still running. I am not sure how to do that. @Stultuske can you help me with some code examples if you know how to achieve this?

Comment: @GauravRaj in aop before: start timewatch. add a getter to check current value.

Comment: You might want to use an `ExecutorService` and execute your potentially long-running code asynchronously, evaluating a `Future` with a timeout as described in [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial). Whether you orchestrate multiple asynchronous tasks using AOP to verify for results or not, is another topic. You also might want to check out [`@Async` in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async).

Answer (score 0):

To check time elapsed till now, you could do something like the below:

```
public final class App {

static long startTime;

public static void runInLoop() throws InterruptedException{
    while(true) {
        //do something assuming which takes around 5 seconds
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        //call to check time taken till now
        timeTaken();
    }
}

public static void timeTaken() throws InterruptedException{

    long lapTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();

    long timeElapsed = lapTime - startTime;

    System.out.println("Execution time in milliseconds: " + timeElapsed);
}


/**
 * Says hello to the world.
 * @param args The arguments of the program.
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // Start timer
    startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
    runInLoop();
}
```

}

Also. to detect infinite loops you can  set your own "max time" after which it shall decide it as "infinite loop" and stop the execution.

Also check the below link for halting problems with infinite loops.
[Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Comment: Here you are calculating time elapsed by calling timeTaken() inside your method. But I want to know the time elapsed even when method execution has not completed. Also I don't want to add any code for this inside my method as there could be multiple such methods.

Comment: Here the time will be calculated after each iteration of the while loop. So `runInLoop()` method execution has not completed. Also if you wish to not add any code, you should consider some profiling tools such as [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)